# Why Walrasian budget set is not compact for p=0?

Tags: analysis, economics

I know that budget set is defined as $B(p,b) = \{x \in R_+^n: p.x \leq b \}$.

If $p \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0$, this budget set is called **Walrasian budget set** or **the competitive budget set**.

I also know that if $p>>0$, then Walrasian budget set is compact.

But why do we need the assumption that $p >> 0$? Why is not it compact for some $p_i = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all $p_i > 0$, then each $x\in B(p, b)$ has $x_i \leq b_i / p_i$ for each $i$. The set $B(p, b)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is then closed and bounded, and thus compact. If some $p_i = 0$, then the projection $\pi_i:B(p, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ on to the $i$th coordinate is the noncompact set $\mathbb{R}^+$, so $B(p, b)$ itself is noncompact.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, the main reason is that I cannot divide by 0 and hence it is not closed? I am really bad at Mathematical analysis... Thank's a lot!

Comment: No. Take $n = 0$ and $p = 0$, for example. Then $B(p, b)$ is $\mathbb{R}^+$ itself, since $p.x = 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. 
But then I do not understand, why it is not compact... I think it is bounded and also closed. Could you give me some hint? I do not know what is wrong with my way of thinking...

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^+$ is not bounded.

Comment: I have never thought that I am so stupid as I really am. :D Thank you for your patience with me.

Comment: You don't have to apologize. Glad it worked out.